# How do I delete Plugins in Firefox 56.0?

Tags: permissions, firefox, plugins

I recently saw that two plugins have been installed on my Firefox installation. I do not need them and want to uninstall them.

[image: image of plugins]

I tried navigating to the addon folder for Firefox but that folder is owned by root. I tried changing the permissions for the folder (/usr/lib/firefox-addons), but had no success. The folder is owned by root and appears empty.

Comment: Normally firefox plugins are installed in your home directory. Type `about:plugins` in the address bar to see the location of the installed plugins. I don't see a reason to delete them, in your case they are not loaded anyway. The `OpenH264 Video Codec'-plugin is preinstalled by mozilla, it comes with firefox and will be reinstalled during an upgrade of firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the help @mook765. I think the only thing you could have added is that the folder is hidden in the home directory, you need to press `ctrl` + `h` to see it. Thanks again for your help! **EDIT**: I delete the plugin folders and restarted firefox, but they still appear in the Add-ons Manager?

Comment: If they're in `/usr/lib/firefox-addons`, then they're installed by some package. Add the output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/firefox-addons`, please.

Comment: I'd like to comment that, the H264 codec is used to view videos using that use this encoding (For example, YouTube uses it). While the other one is used to stream DRM videos (For example, Netflix uses it).

Comment: @Berrik I see, same thing on my machine. Try George's answer or refresh firefox (this will reset your profile to factory state, this will keep OpenH264-plugin of course). Here one more link: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cannot-remove-add-on-extension-or-theme#w_uninstalling-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps to manually remove them:

1. Type about:plugins into the address bar and press Enter to display the About Plugins page.
2. Each entry in the About Plugins page will have "File:" and "Path:", showing the name and location of the plugin file. Navigate to the folder shown for the plugin you want to remove.
3. Rename the file to add an X in front of the filename (for instance, npswf32 becomes Xnpswf32).

Source:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems#w_manually-uninstalling-a-plugin